# Can I generalize GADTs that use type tags?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I wrote an alpha-beta search in Haskell that uses the `NextMoveTag` type family to ensure that the game state and moves generated from that game state are valid for the player whose turn it is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, EmptyDataDecls, DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

data MoveTag = ComputerMoveTag | PlayerMoveTag
type family NextMoveTag a where
    NextMoveTag PlayerMoveTag = ComputerMoveTag
    NextMoveTag ComputerMoveTag = PlayerMoveTag

data Move (t :: MoveTag) where
    ComputerMove :: CardFace -> Row -> Col -> Move ComputerMoveTag
    PlayerMove :: Direction -> Move PlayerMoveTag

data Game (t :: MoveTag) where
    PlayerTurnGame :: Board -> Deck -> Game PlayerMoveTag
    ComputerTurnGame :: Board -> Deck -> Move PlayerMoveTag -> Game ComputerMoveTag

staticEvaluator :: (Num f) => Game t -> f
nextGameStates :: Game t -> [(Move t, Game (NextMoveTag t))]
```

Now I would like to generalize the code so that I can plug in any game, i.e.

```
class Minimaxable g where
    staticEvaluator :: ???
    nextGameStates :: ???
```

But how do I write the types? Can I?

A problem I run into when I try to write this is that the first step of `alphabeta` is to check whose turn it is by pattern-matching on `g`:

```
alphabeta depth alpha beta game@(PlayerTurnGame _ _) = ...
```

Comment: By the way, I'm not fluent with the relevant terminology. I did the best I could with the question title, but edits are welcome.

Comment: a short search revealed a package: [game-tree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/game-tree) - maybe you can make some use of it (or at least have a look at the design)

Comment: You could use kinds https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind

Comment: A short read revealed that game-tree's types aren't nearly as cool as my types. :) But yeah, maybe I should use it anyway. I'll see! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by being able to plug in "any game". Is every game going to have a `MoveTag` denoting whose turn it is? If so, then you can give `g` a kind signature and define the type class as

```
class Minimaxable (g :: MoveTag -> *) where
    type GameMove g :: MoveTag -> *

    staticEvaluator :: Num f => g t -> f
    nextGameStates :: g t -> [(GameMove g t, g (NextMoveTag t))]
```

The `Move` type is plugged in as an associated type synonym as it will probably vary between different types of games.

Now you can define an instance for your existing game type as

```
instance Minimaxable Game where
    type GameMove Game = Move

    staticEvaluator = ...
    nextGameStates  = ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of moving `GameMove` into the class like that. I was also hung up on Minimaxable knowing about `Game` so that `alphabeta` could see whose turn it was with pattern matching, but adding `whoseTurn :: g t -> MoveTag` worked as well.